# headers on one.com not being executed and no errors given

Tags: php

I am creating a login system for my website, when the user is logged in I am using a header call to redirect them to another page, the header call is not executing and I am not getting any errors, although I do have one.com error report turned on.

login validation

```
if (isset($_POST['login'])&& $_POST['login'] !== "") { 

    $log = $login->check_login($username);
    if ($log) {
        // Registration Success

       header("Location: http://joshpercival.co.uk/webapp/indx.php");
    } else {
        // Registration Failed
        $password_error='Wrong username or password';
    }
}
```

login class

```
public function check_login($username) {

    $sql2="SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE username='$username'";
       //checking if the username is available in the table
       $check = Database::getInstance()->getConnection()->query($sql2);
       $count_row = $check->num_rows;


    if ($count_row == 1) {
        // this login var will use for the session thing

        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_data['user_id'];
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: First tag the framework whatever you are using.

Comment: im not using a framework i have created the functions

Comment: Have you check that what `check_login()` returns?

Comment: the check login returns i echo messages without the header call

Comment: The header is only work when you doesn't outputting before header call. Check this.

Comment: im not outputting before the header call

Comment: Ok, do one thing write like this before your if `if ($log) { echo "inside if"; die(); } else { echo "inside else"; die(); }` and run that file again and let me know what it echoing.